# Return Boolean (1 or 0) if table contains duplicate rows

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql, shark-sql

I wish to return a boolean value if there are duplicates in the table in Hive 0.9 
For now, I'm doing this :

```sql
select cast(case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as smallint) Validate_Value 
from  (
    select guid, count(guid) cnt 
    from default.vms_feed v 
    group by guid
) where v.cnt > 1 ;
```

But this gives me an error:

> "cannot recognize input near 'where' 'v' '.' in subquery source [DB Errorcode=11]
>   "

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing out here !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax for Hive subquery is:

```
SELECT ... FROM (subquery) name ...
```

So in your case

```
SELECT CAST(...) Validate_Value 
FROM (
   ... 
) v WHERE v.cnt > 1 ;
```